# does mysql.connector work with postgreeSQL?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I am developing an app which uses MariaDB and mysql.connector for python. However, I reached to some point where I see that PostgreSQL could have benefits (e.g. it exists RETURNING). If I create again the database using Postgre, will I have to modify code related with mysql.connector in python? Or is the library totally compatible? If it's not, which library do I have to use?

Comment: mysql.connector is for connecting to MySQL and MySQL only. (Maria DB happens to be 100% compatible replacement for historical reasons.) Postgres is a completely different database and needs a completely different connector.

Comment: MariaDB has [RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/) as well.

Comment: But it's an expression for del and insert a complete row, isn't it? I think it's different from a simple UPDATE of a cell as I want. At least you cannot use RETURNING with UPDATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a new library. You need to install psycopg2 or psycopg-binary depending on your operating system.

This link is a detailed tutorial https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/

Comment: Thank you. They even seem to share methods and properties. That's nice.